Accessing objects in React
I am unable to access objects returned from a functional component in React. I need to format one into JSX and return another as a string (for an API call) in the main app.
ProfileData.js: returns objects graphData.mail and graphData.displayName
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// Msal imports
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { InteractionStatus, InteractionRequiredAuthError } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import { loginRequest } from "./authConfig";
import { callMsGraph } from "./components/MsGraphApiCall";


const ProfileData = () => {
  const { instance, inProgress } = useMsal();
  const [graphData, setGraphData] = useState({ mail: '', displayName: null });

  useEffect(() => {
      if (!graphData && inProgress === InteractionStatus.None) {
          callMsGraph().then(response => setGraphData({ mail: response.mail, displayName: response.displayName })).catch((e) => {
              if (e instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
                  instance.acquireTokenRedirect({
                      ...loginRequest,
                      account: instance.getActiveAccount()
                  });
              }
          });
      }
  }, [inProgress, graphData, instance]);
 
  return (
    {graphData}
  );
};

export default ProfileData;

utils.js: format graphData.displayName into JSX and graphData.mail into a string
export const NameContent = ({ProfileData}) => {
    return (
        <div className="nameContent" align="center">
            <IconButton href="https://myaccount.microsoft.com" target="_tab" color="inherit"><AccountCircleOutlinedIcon />&nbsp;{ProfileData.displayName}</IconButton>
        </div>
    );
};

export const EmailContent = ({ProfileData}) => {
    return (
       {ProfileData.mail}
    );
};

app.js: Display graphData.displayName and use graphData.mail in an API call
<Typography variant="h5" align="right"> <utils.NameContent /></Typography>

let url = `${utils.RUNTIME_BACKEND_URL}/data?email={utils.EmailContent};


Your understanding of how this is supposed to work is wrong in too many ways to really know where to begin. Components don't return objects. They render things. You are not passing ProfileData to NameContent, you just gave the parameter the same name.


I am unable to access objects returned from a functional component in React.

That is by design. React components must return React elements, which are built by React, and are not supposed to be accessed manually.
Of course you can return whatever you want from any javascript function, but if you force a React component to return a custom value, then it is not a valid React component anymore, and an error will occur at some point sooner or later.
Right now you are trying to build some data inside a React component, return the result, and render the actual view somewhere else.
I think the way to go (and to think) would be the other way around: to render the view inside the React component, and extract the logic that calculates the data into a custom hook.
